# Disable Google Chrome URL Bar

Tags: windows, google-chrome, address-bar

Is there a way I can disable typing in Google Chrome's URL bar or hide it in the current version? I know about Kiosk mode but it removes the tool bars and tabs.

Comment: Does fullscreen mode not solve your issue? Press `F11` to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if you are on Windows)

That exits presentation mode and (I think) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**For Chrome Dev Version:**

- Open about:flags
- Enable 'Compact Navigation'. restart chrome
- Right-click on a tab and select 'Hide the toolbar'

This hides the address bar by default. For current tab you can use 'ctrl-L' to show the address bar and 'escape' to hide it

Taken from [This](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/FJQ9wmSZQKo/xUOsgrOtwyAJ) Products forum post.